# Concurrent in-order processing of work items from a Java BlockingQueue

Tags: java, performance, concurrency, queue

I have part of a system that processes a `BlockingQueue` of input items within a worker thread, and puts the results on an `BlockingQueue` of output items, where the relevant code (simplified) looks something like this:

```java
while (running()) {
   InputObject a=inputQueue.take();   // Get from input BlockingQueue
   OutputObject b=doProcessing(a);    // Process the item 
   outputQueue.put(b);                // Place on output BlockingQueue
}
```

`doProcessing` is the main performance bottleneck in this code, but the processing of queue items could be parallelised since the processing steps are all independent of each other.

I would therefore like to improve this so that items can be processed concurrently by multiple threads, with the constraint that this **must not change the order** of outputs (e.g. I can't simply have 10 threads running the loop above, because that might result in outputs being ordered differently depending on processing times).

What is the best way to achieve this in pure, idiomatic Java?

Comment: If the second task finishes before the first task, should the thread executing the second task block? Or should the thread executing the second task go and execute another task and let the thread executing the first task handle enqueuing the results of both the first task and second task? Note in both approaches I'm letting the thread executing `doProcess` be responsible for enqueuing the `OutputObject`.

Comment: It's best if none of the worker threads block (I'm assuming some sort of thread pool, so we want to return the threads to the pool as soon as they have done their `doProcessing` work). It's fine for the main thread driving the queue to block assuming there is no more input waiting to be processed.

Comment: I came up with something like this: https://gist.github.com/tkslaw/24099d8ff2a515022d3162b6a5b86e1b. Is that what you're looking for? Note I haven't rigorously tested the code but it appears to work. I'm also not sure if there's higher-level constructs out there that could simply the implementation of the `Task` class I created (for example, I tried to use `CompletableFuture` but failed). Essentially what I did is create a pseudo linked list of tasks that complete subsequent tasks as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Parallel streams from `List` preserve ordering:

```
List<T> input = ...
List<T> output = input.parallelStream()
                .filter(this::running)
                .map(this::doProcessing)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

[`PriorityBlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html) can be used if your work items can be compared to one another, and you will wait until `running()` is `false` before reading from the output queue:

```
outputQueue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<>();
```

---

Or you could order them after they have all been processed (if they can be compared to one another):

```
outputQueue.drainTo(outputList);
outputList.sort(null);
```

---

A simple way to implement comparation would be assigning a progressive ID to each element put into the input queue.

Answer (score 1):

Create X event-loop threads, where X is the amount of steps that can be processed in parallel.

They *will* be processed in parallel, except one after another, i.e. not on the same item. While one step will be carried on on one item, the previous step will be carried on on the previous item, etc.

To further optimize it, you can use concurrent queues provided by [JCTools](https://github.com/JCTools/JCTools), which are optimized for Single-Producer Single-Consumer scenarios (JDK's `BlockingQueue` implementations support Multiple-Producer Multiple-Consumer).

```
// Thread 1
while (running()) {
    InputObject a = inputQueue.take();
    OutputObject b = doProcessingStep1(a);
    queue1.put(b);
}
```

```
// Thread 2
while (running()) {
    InputObject a = queue1.take();
    OutputObject b = doProcessingStep2(a);
    queue2.put(b);
}
```

```
// Thread 3
while (running()) {
    InputObject a = queue2.take();
    OutputObject b = doProcessingStep3(a);
    outputQueue.put(b);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I see how this works but this doesn't seem to allow the single processing step to be carried out in parallel, instead it breaks the processing step into different stages (which is an an interesting idea, but not quite what I am looking for).